# How encode GKComponentSystem<GKComponent> object

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

I'm stuck trying to encode an array.

I have a class as following:

```
class EnemyMoveComponentSystem: GKComponentSystem<GKComponent> {

    func updateWithDeltaTime(seconds: TimeInterval, gameScene: GameScene) {

        for component in components {
            if let enemyMoveComponent = component as? EnemyMoveComponent {
                enemyMoveComponent.update(deltaTime: seconds, gameScene: gameScene)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I declared an array as following:

```
var enemyMoveComponentSystems: [EnemyMoveComponentSystem] = []
```

However, when i tried to encode the array as below I get error:

```
override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(enemyMoveComponentSystems, forKey: "Scene.enemyMoveComponentSystems")
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You are trying to encode an Array (Swift Array) into an NSCoder,  I do not think bridging a swift array into an NSArray is done anymore for free.